# can i get df-h with full percent on disk volume?

Tags: linux

all i get is round percentage:

```
[root@UML-0297 ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-os
                   15G   14G  244M  99% /
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-sdisk
                   15G  6.4G  7.1G  48% /servicedisk
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-snaps
                   71G  4.7G   63G   7% /snapshots
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-crashdumps
                   76G  180M   72G   1% /var/crash
/dev/sda1              99M   39M   55M  42% /boot
tmpfs                  12G   92K   12G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sdbz              53T  1.9T   52T   4% /fs1
17.0.0.3:/fs1/         53T  1.9T   52T   4% /mnt/bwfs
```

Comment: And why the rounded percentage is not enough?

Comment: cause i need the exact percentage

Comment: But why do you need that?

Comment: for a project at work

Comment: This is a meaningless answer. What is the real reason requiring the exact percentage? Why do you use `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want percentage with fractional digits, à la `12.579%`, then try:

```
  df|awk '/dev/{if ($2>0.0) {printf "%s: %.3f%%\n", $1, 100.0*$3/$2;}}'
```

Perhaps you want [disk quotas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota), or use [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) with `--file-system`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you asking, but you can try **df -a** that will display you all info include dummy file systems. Also you can run: **man df** and find more information